# How to pass an angularjs variable value to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In this code I'm attempting to pass a AngularJS paramter to a function :

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
    <p><a href='javascript:display({{ user.firstName }});'>{{ user.firstName }}</a>
</div>

function LoginController($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        firstName: "Foo"
    };
}

function display(text){
    alert(text)
}
```

When "Foo" is clicked "Foo" should be displayed but how to pass an angularjs variable value to a javascript function ?

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/534/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the value, `"Foo"`, is being written out as part of code. In this case, appearing to be a variable that doesn't exist.

```
display(Foo) // ReferenceError: Foo is not defined
```

It'll need to at least be quoted to be understood as a string value.

```
display('Foo')
```

You can use the [`json` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json) to do this to include any necessary escape sequences.

```
<a href='javascript:display({{ user.firstName|json }});'>{{ user.firstName }}</a>
```

---

Or, if you attach the function to the `$scope`, you can reference it and the value without `{{...}}` or filters in an [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick):

```
function LoginController($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        firstName: "Foo"
    };

    $scope.display = function (text) {
        alert(text);
    };

    // or keep the global function and reference it on the $scope
    // $scope.display = display;
}
```

```
<a ng-click="display(user.firstName)">{{user.firstName}}</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7z4wmnjj/

Answer (score 3):

Doing this would work, but only for strings.

```
<p><a href='javascript:display("{{ user.firstName }}");'>{{ user.firstName }}</a>
```

This might be a bit of a deep dive into Angular, but you should think about implementing a factory which can explicitly handle this behaviour for you.

We can make a function that takes a name and any number of arguments and passes the arguments on to the Javascript function with that name. It can work like this:

```
<a ng-click='callJS("display", user.firstName)'></a>
```

And it can be implemented in a fairly straightforward way.

```
// register a new factory on our module
app.factory('callJS', function() {
  // a factory returns one value
  return function(fnName) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1),
        fn = window.fnName;

    return fn.apply(fn, args);
  };
});
```

Then all you need to do to use the service is inject it and make it available on the `$scope` object.

```
function LoginController($scope, callJS) {
  $scope.callJS = callJS;

  $scope.user = {
    firstName: "Foo"
  };
}
```

Taking this approach means you won't be limited to just click events either, as long as `callJS` is in the local scope, any Angular expression will be able to call Javascript functions.

This is more flexible, more testable and easier to debug, than templating variables into `href` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

First step in JS debugging should always be to open your console.

```
<p>
  <a href='javascript:display('{{ user.firstName }}');'>{{ user.firstName }}</a>
</p>
```